# mongo aggregation calculate the difference of timestamp between different documents

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mapreduce

----Updated----

I know there are some posts that already explained how to use `$subtract` in Mongo aggregation, but I still confused about how to solve this issue.

Below are some example documents, the docs record the behaviour of user's action,

user 001 enter the index.html at  1457578406751, and leave the index.html at 1457578433076, so by subtracting the timestamp of log1 and log2 I can know how long does user 001 stay on index.html.

User action is defined as : userA enter a.html ---(t1)-- leave a.html ---- enter b.html --(t2)--leave b.html ----enter a.html --(t3)-- leave a.html......., after a series action,  userA close the browser. 
what I need to do is: calculate  t1,t2,t3

every time user makes an action, system output a log, as shown in the example, so for one user there may have lots of logs, even more for multiple user.

**My Question:** 
how can I calculate the time interval according to uid and alias?

My thought is: first find  all unique uids in all logs, then for different alias in those unique uids get the timestamps and put them in to an array, do the subtract. I wrote some pseudo code, not sure if it's right

```
for uid in log{    
  for alias in uid{
      arr =  Array.new  
      diff = Array.new  //diff.length = arr.length/2
      put timestamp to arr  //list of timestamp for a uid
        for i in diff.length
           diff[i] = arr[2*i]- arr[2*i-1]
   }  
}
```

**Or** can I simply do this with Mongo aggregation or Mongo map-reduce?  really need some ideas, hope someone can help me out. BTW, I'm using ruby. Thanks

```
log1: {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('56e13073b3afca038b8b4567'), 
"action"=>"PageEnter", 
"timestamp"=>"1457578406751", 
"alias"=>"index.html", 
"uid"=>"001"}


log2: {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('56e13073b3afca038b8b4568'), 
 "action"=>"PageQuit",
 "timestamp"=>"1457578433076", 
"alias"=>"index.html", 
"uid"=>"001"}

log3:{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('xxxxxxx'), 
 "action"=>"PageEnter",
 "timestamp"=>"1557578433076", 
"alias"=>"contact.html", 
"uid"=>"002"}

log4:{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('xxxxxxx'), 
 "action"=>"PageQuit",
 "timestamp"=>"1557578433086", 
"alias"=>"contact.html", 
"uid"=>"002"}
 .
 .
 .
logn:{}
```

Comment: The aggregation framework cannot really operate on more than one document ( or grouped document ) at a time. What you are asking for requires "globals" in order to compare one result to the other. It's possible with mapReduce, but it's also possible by simply iterating the data and inspecting each value for the difference. It's not clear if you want a "total difference" per "uid" or just the difference between two documents.

Comment: FYI. You really need to fix your data. All the "timestamp" values are "strings", so everything would need to be converted to a number. Saves on storage space as well. Even BSON Date types actually use the "numeric" timestamp value internally.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I updated my post, hope it is clear enough. about the timestamp data type , I already fixed it. Thanks !!